# Swift - UIStackView - hide if height of all items is below threshold

Tags: uibutton, uistackview, layoutsubviews

I have `UIStackView` in vertical mode filled with `UIButtons`. I have dynamic screen resize and if all buttons in stack view have height under some threshold, I want to hide them. How to achive this automatically?

I have tried to extend `UIButton` and add:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    self.isHidden = (self.frame.height < 20)
}
```

which works, but once the button is hidden it will never re-appear and `layoutSubviews` is never called back (even if the height should be again larger).

Comment: Is your stack view set to `distribution = .fillEqually`, so all the buttons are the same height? Do you need to set `.isHidden`, or would setting `.alpha = 0.0` / `.alpha = 1.0` be a suitable option? (Buttons with `.alpha = 0.0` do **NOT** accept touches.)

Comment: @DonMag Yes, all buttons are the same height. Set `alpha` to zero is problematic, since the buttons are transparent based on some other information which have to be recreated when they "appear" again. However, if it is the only option, it can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what all you are doing, or why you say it would be problematic to set the buttons' `.alpha` property, but here are two approaches, both using a `UIStackView` subclass and handling the show/hide in `layoutSubviews()`.

1: calculate what the button heights *will be* and set `.isHidden` property:

```
class MyStackView: UIStackView {
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        axis = .vertical
        distribution = .fillEqually
        spacing = 8
    }
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        // approach 1
        //  setting .isHidden
        let numViews = arrangedSubviews.count
        let numSpaces = numViews - 1
        let h = (bounds.height - (spacing * CGFloat(numSpaces))) / CGFloat(numViews)
        let bHide = h < 20
        arrangedSubviews.forEach { v in
            v.isHidden = bHide
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

2. set `.isHidden` property based on what the button heights *are* (much simpler):

   class MyStackView: UIStackView {

   ```
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        axis = .vertical
        distribution = .fillEqually
        spacing = 8
    }
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        // approach 2
        //  setting .alpha
        arrangedSubviews.forEach { v in
            v.alpha = v.frame.height < 20 ? 0.0 : 1.0
        }

    }
   ```

   }

And here's a sample controller to see it in use. Tapping anywhere will toggle the height of the stack view between `300` and `100` (buttons will have less-than 20-pts height at `100`):

```
class ConditionalStackViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let stackView: MyStackView = {
        let v = MyStackView()
        // so we can see the stack view frame
        v.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
    }()
    
    var stackHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        for i in 1...6 {
            let b = UIButton()
            b.setTitle("Button \(i)", for: [])
            b.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
            b.setTitleColor(.lightGray, for: .highlighted)
            b.backgroundColor = .red
            stackView.addArrangedSubview(b)
        }
        
        view.addSubview(stackView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        stackHeight = stackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300.0)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            stackHeight,
        ])
        
        let t = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(gotTap(_:)))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(t)
    }
    
    @objc func gotTap(_ g: UITapGestureRecognizer) -> Void {
        stackHeight.constant = stackHeight.constant == 300 ? 100 : 300
    }

}
```